# Excel lookup / value formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

Ok hard to describe this one.

I want to be able to create a formula where part of the formula is populated by info in another field.

e.g.

**Sheet 1**
A1 = TXT - A2
A2 = number - 1599

**Sheet 2**
A1 = formula - =Sheet1!"A1"

so with a normal formula of "=Sheet1!A1" your would get the answer A2.  what I want is the formula to populate the answer so it changes to "=Sheet1!A2" as A2 is txt in A1 giving me a formula answer of "1599"

I hope that makes sense :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the INDIRECT function in Sheet2 A1 cell:

Sheet2, A1:   "=INDIRECT(Sheet1!A1)"

[office reference](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/indirect-function-HP010342609.aspx)

Comment: that works but only on the sheet im in e.g. if im on sheet2 it comes back with the Sheet2!A2 if I change the txt in Sheet1 A1 to say Sheet!A2 it works perfectly. do you know a way to have the "Sheet!" part in the formula and the only bring back the txt for filed ref?

Comment: Sorry typo in that. if I change the txt to say Sheet1!A2 it works

Comment: I think you can use `=INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&A1)` similar to the example in row 10 of the reference link. Not tested that...

Comment: Your amazing :) I have been messing around with this all morning :) thank you

Comment: we are fast here on superuser :) - Actually, I think it should be `=INDIRECT("Sheet1!" & Sheet1!A1)` in your case to work always. I don't know what problem you are trying to solve but usually using Named cells or vlookup tables solve this kind of situation nicely too.

Comment: I have 2 spreadsheets. 1 is full of stock information, waist, sales so on and so on. at the moment the 2nd sheet has separate sheets for each week of the month. in each field it has a unique ="otherspreadsheet\sheetname\filedname" then formulas adding and subtracking so on so forth. so im creating a single sheet with 1 - 52 listed then the different filed names for each sheet needed.

Comment: the new sheet has a box at the top they can select week 1 - 52 then each field does a vlookup depending on that number and pulls back the filed number needed for that section. Long winded that's why I cut it down :) lol so the indirect is just 1 part of the actual formula but it works a treat